# the id "" is not defined anywhere in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have this error in Android Studio's Java code which says that the id "textDateTime" is not defined anywhere.

how do I define it? And is it okay if I just Suppress (ignore the unknown id) and move on?

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

<EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputNoteSubtitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_12sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_12sdp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_medium"
            android:hint="@string/note_subtitle"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextSubtitle"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorTextHint"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_13ssp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textDateTime" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: if you have  textDateTime view in your layout ,you can run.

Answer (score -1):

You have reference to this ID on your layout

```
 app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textDateTime"
```

just remove this line if there no any view with this ID in your layout.

Comment: That will also not fix my problem because the text hint which is Note Subtitle's layout will be somewhere else.